# Adding LINQ select queries to expression in loop

Tags: c#, linq

I have a menu that dynamically populates a list of ToggleMenuFlyoutItems.

Now I want to filter a list based on the checked items in the ToggleMenuFlyoutItem list.

```
foreach(var treslag in TreeTypeFlyout.Items)
{
    var flyoutItem = treslag as ToggleMenuFlyoutItem;

    if (flyoutItem.IsChecked)
    {
        tempStems = tempStems.Where(x => 
                        x.SpeciesGroupName.ToLower() == flyoutItem.Text.ToLower());
    }
}
```

What I expect from this code is that my linq query expression is populated with a bunch of where clauses, but it's always one expression. It does not seem to add an expression for each checked item.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think it would work anyway; multiple Where compound to an AND, not an OR

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a `List` to fill `tempStems` filter objects.

```
List<Type_of_tempStems> list =new List<Type_of_tempStems>();

foreach(var treslag in TreeTypeFlyout.Items)
{
    var flyoutItem = treslag as ToggleMenuFlyoutItem;

    if (flyoutItem.IsChecked)
    {
        list.AddRange(tempStems.Where(x => x.SpeciesGroupName.ToLower() == flyoutItem.Text.ToLower()));
    }
}
```

If I understand correctly you can try to use lambda `Where` and `Join` to make it.

```
TreeTypeFlyout.Items
    .Where(x=>x.IsChecked)
    .Join(x=> x.Text.ToLower(),y=>y.SpeciesGroupName.ToLower(),(x,y)=>y);
```